# Conditionally add/remove attribute in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to disable an input based on a boolean value from a checkbox selected in the form. Sadly this doesn't work -

```
<input type="number" ng-model="data.age" ng-attr-disabled={data.checked ? 'disabled'}>
```

How to fix this?

Looking for a pure Angular solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a need to use `ng-attr-disabled`. The simplest option would be to use `ng-disabled` with your boolean value

```
<input type="number" ng-model="data.age" ng-disabled="data.checked">
```

You have also not provided enough information to determine whether the `data.checked` variable is being correctly set or even exists.

Comment: Is there a more generic solution? I have other attributes as well.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. ng-disabled is the standard angular method for disabling fields.

Comment: What you mentioned works for me. I am just curious as to is there a generic solution if say i need to add/remove any other attribute - let's say placeholder?

Comment: Glad my answer solved your problem. As to what you refer to as a generic solution, without a more concrete example I am at a loss.

Comment: Will try to frame one and provide. Thanks.

Comment: I think you should probably do that in a seperate question, with a title that may attract some other angular programmers. Close this question by accepting my answer. as it has been answered it may not attract many more views from others